# Can't install atom-text editor

Tags: installation, atom-editor

Atom vanished from my computer, and when i try to install it, it fails ...

this is the log.... anyone know what i should do ?

> 2017-08-29 12:59:28> Program: Starting Squirrel Updater: --install .
>   --rerunningWithoutUAC 2017-08-29 12:59:28> Program: Starting install, writing to C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\SquirrelTemp 2017-08-29
>   12:59:28> Program: About to install to:
>   C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\atom 2017-08-29 12:59:28> Program:
>   Install path C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\atom already exists, burning
>   it to the ground 2017-08-29 12:59:29> Utility: DeleteDirectory: could
>   not delete -
>   C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.19.4\resources\app\apm\node_modules\es5-ext\array#:
>   System.IO.IOException: The directory is not empty.
>
> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String
>   maybeFullPath)    at System.IO.Directory.DeleteHelper(String fullPath,
>   String userPath, Boolean recursive, Boolean
>   throwOnTopLevelDirectoryNotFound)    at
>   System.IO.Directory.Delete(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean
>   recursive, Boolean checkHost)    at
>   Squirrel.Utility.d__19.MoveNext() 2017-08-29
>   12:59:29> Utility: DeleteDirectory: could not delete -
>   C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.19.4\resources\app\apm\node_modules\es5-ext\array:
>   System.IO.IOException: The directory is not empty.
>
> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String
>   maybeFullPath)    at System.IO.Directory.DeleteHelper(String fullPath,
>   String userPath, Boolean recursive, Boolean
>   throwOnTopLevelDirectoryNotFound)    at
>   System.IO.Directory.Delete(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean
>   recursive, Boolean checkHost)    at
>   Squirrel.Utility.d__19.MoveNext() 2017-08-29
>   12:59:29> Utility: DeleteDirectory: could not delete -
>   C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.19.4\resources\app\apm\node_modules\es5-ext:
>   System.IO.IOException: The directory is not empty.
>
> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String
>   maybeFullPath)    at System.IO.Directory.DeleteHelper(String fullPath,
>   String userPath, Boolean recursive, Boolean
>   throwOnTopLevelDirectoryNotFound)    at
>   System.IO.Directory.Delete(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean
>   recursive, Boolean checkHost)    at
>   Squirrel.Utility.d__19.MoveNext() 2017-08-29
>   12:59:29> Utility: DeleteDirectory: could not delete -
>   C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.19.4\resources\app\apm\node_modules:
>   System.IO.IOException: The directory is not empty.
>
> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String
>   maybeFullPath)    at System.IO.Directory.DeleteHelper(String fullPath,
>   String userPath, Boolean recursive, Boolean
>   throwOnTopLevelDirectoryNotFound)    at
>   System.IO.Directory.Delete(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean
>   recursive, Boolean checkHost)    at
>   Squirrel.Utility.d__19.MoveNext() 2017-08-29
>   12:59:29> Utility: DeleteDirectory: could not delete -
>   C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.19.4\resources\app\apm:
>   System.IO.IOException: The directory is not empty.
>
> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String
>   maybeFullPath)    at System.IO.Directory.DeleteHelper(String fullPath,
>   String userPath, Boolean recursive, Boolean
>   throwOnTopLevelDirectoryNotFound)    at
>   System.IO.Directory.Delete(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean
>   recursive, Boolean checkHost)    at
>   Squirrel.Utility.d__19.MoveNext() 2017-08-29
>   12:59:29> Utility: DeleteDirectory: could not delete -
>   C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.19.4\resources\app:
>   System.IO.IOException: The directory is not empty.
>
> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String
>   maybeFullPath)    at System.IO.Directory.DeleteHelper(String fullPath,
>   String userPath, Boolean recursive, Boolean
>   throwOnTopLevelDirectoryNotFound)    at
>   System.IO.Directory.Delete(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean
>   recursive, Boolean checkHost)    at
>   Squirrel.Utility.d__19.MoveNext() 2017-08-29
>   12:59:29> Utility: DeleteDirectory: could not delete -
>   C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.19.4\resources:
>   System.IO.IOException: The directory is not empty.
>
> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String
>   maybeFullPath)    at System.IO.Directory.DeleteHelper(String fullPath,
>   String userPath, Boolean recursive, Boolean
>   throwOnTopLevelDirectoryNotFound)    at
>   System.IO.Directory.Delete(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean
>   recursive, Boolean checkHost)    at
>   Squirrel.Utility.d__19.MoveNext() 2017-08-29
>   12:59:29> Utility: DeleteDirectory: could not delete -
>   C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.19.4: System.IO.IOException:
>   The directory is not empty.
>
> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String
>   maybeFullPath)    at System.IO.Directory.DeleteHelper(String fullPath,
>   String userPath, Boolean recursive, Boolean
>   throwOnTopLevelDirectoryNotFound)    at
>   System.IO.Directory.Delete(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean
>   recursive, Boolean checkHost)    at
>   Squirrel.Utility.d__19.MoveNext() 2017-08-29
>   12:59:29> IEnableLogger: Failed to remove existing directory on full
>   install, is the app still running???: System.IO.IOException: The
>   process cannot access the file
>   'C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\atom\packages\atom-1.19.4-full.nupkg'
>   because it is being used by another process.    at
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>   at System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path, Boolean checkHost)    at
>   System.IO.File.Delete(String path)    at
>   Squirrel.Utility.<>c.b__19_0(String file)    at
>   Squirrel.Utility.<>c__DisplayClass12_1`1.<ForEachAsync>b__1()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Squirrel.Utility.<>c__DisplayClass13_0`1.<b__1>d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at Squirrel.Utility.d__19.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Squirrel.Utility.<>c.<b__19_1>d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Squirrel.Utility.<>c__DisplayClass13_0`1.<<ForEachAsync>b__1>d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at Squirrel.Utility.<DeleteDirectory>d__19.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at Squirrel.Utility.<LogIfThrows>d__42.MoveNext() 2017-08-29
>   12:59:29> Unhandled exception: System.AggregateException: One or more
>   errors occurred. ---> System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access
>   the file
>   'C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\atom\packages\atom-1.19.4-full.nupkg'
>   because it is being used by another process.    at
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>
>   at System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path, Boolean checkHost)    at
>   System.IO.File.Delete(String path)    at
>   Squirrel.Utility.<>c.<DeleteDirectory>b__19_0(String file)    at
>   Squirrel.Utility.<>c__DisplayClass12_1`1.b__1()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Squirrel.Utility.<>c__DisplayClass13_0`1.<<ForEachAsync>b__1>d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at Squirrel.Utility.<DeleteDirectory>d__19.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Squirrel.Utility.<>c.<<DeleteDirectory>b__19_1>d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Squirrel.Utility.<>c__DisplayClass13_0`1.<b__1>d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at Squirrel.Utility.d__19.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at Squirrel.Utility.d__42.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
>   at Squirrel.Update.Program.d__4.MoveNext()    --- End of
>   inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
>   includeTaskCanceledExceptions)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()    at
>   Squirrel.Update.Program.executeCommandLine(String[] args)    at
>   Squirrel.Update.Program.main(String[] args)
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file
>   'C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\atom\packages\atom-1.19.4-full.nupkg'
>   because it is being used by another process.    at
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>   at System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path, Boolean checkHost)    at
>   System.IO.File.Delete(String path)    at
>   Squirrel.Utility.<>c.b__19_0(String file)    at
>   Squirrel.Utility.<>c__DisplayClass12_1`1.<ForEachAsync>b__1()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Squirrel.Utility.<>c__DisplayClass13_0`1.<b__1>d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at Squirrel.Utility.d__19.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Squirrel.Utility.<>c.<b__19_1>d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Squirrel.Utility.<>c__DisplayClass13_0`1.<b__1>d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at Squirrel.Utility.d__19.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at Squirrel.Utility.d__42.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
>   at Squirrel.Update.Program.d__4.MoveNext()<---
>
> 2017-08-29 13:03:46> Program: Starting Squirrel Updater: --install .
>   --rerunningWithoutUAC 2017-08-29 13:03:47> Program: Starting install, writing to C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\SquirrelTemp 2017-08-29
>   13:03:47> Program: About to install to:
>   C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\atom 2017-08-29 13:03:47> Program:
>   Install path C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\atom already exists, burning
>   it to the ground 2017-08-29 13:04:06> Utility: DeleteDirectory: could
>   not delete -
>   C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.19.4\resources\app\node_modules:
>   System.IO.IOException: The directory is not empty.
>
> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String
>   maybeFullPath)    at System.IO.Directory.DeleteHelper(String fullPath,
>   String userPath, Boolean recursive, Boolean
>   throwOnTopLevelDirectoryNotFound)    at
>   System.IO.Directory.Delete(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean
>   recursive, Boolean checkHost)    at
>   Squirrel.Utility.d__19.MoveNext() 2017-08-29
>   13:04:06> Utility: DeleteDirectory: could not delete -
>   C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.19.4\resources\app:
>   System.IO.IOException: The directory is not empty.
>
> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String
>   maybeFullPath)    at System.IO.Directory.DeleteHelper(String fullPath,
>   String userPath, Boolean recursive, Boolean
>   throwOnTopLevelDirectoryNotFound)    at
>   System.IO.Directory.Delete(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean
>   recursive, Boolean checkHost)    at
>   Squirrel.Utility.d__19.MoveNext() 2017-08-29
>   13:04:06> Utility: DeleteDirectory: could not delete -
>   C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.19.4\resources:
>   System.IO.IOException: The directory is not empty.
>
> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String
>   maybeFullPath)    at System.IO.Directory.DeleteHelper(String fullPath,
>   String userPath, Boolean recursive, Boolean
>   throwOnTopLevelDirectoryNotFound)    at
>   System.IO.Directory.Delete(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean
>   recursive, Boolean checkHost)    at
>   Squirrel.Utility.d__19.MoveNext() 2017-08-29
>   13:04:06> Utility: DeleteDirectory: could not delete -
>   C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.19.4: System.IO.IOException:
>   The directory is not empty.
>
> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String
>   maybeFullPath)    at System.IO.Directory.DeleteHelper(String fullPath,
>   String userPath, Boolean recursive, Boolean
>   throwOnTopLevelDirectoryNotFound)    at
>   System.IO.Directory.Delete(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean
>   recursive, Boolean checkHost)    at
>   Squirrel.Utility.d__19.MoveNext() 2017-08-29
>   13:04:06> IEnableLogger: Failed to remove existing directory on full
>   install, is the app still running???: System.IO.IOException: The
>   process cannot access the file
>   'C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\atom\packages\atom-1.19.4-full.nupkg'
>   because it is being used by another process.    at
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>   at System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path, Boolean checkHost)    at
>   System.IO.File.Delete(String path)    at
>   Squirrel.Utility.<>c.b__19_0(String file)    at
>   Squirrel.Utility.<>c__DisplayClass12_1`1.<ForEachAsync>b__1()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Squirrel.Utility.<>c__DisplayClass13_0`1.<b__1>d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at Squirrel.Utility.d__19.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Squirrel.Utility.<>c.<b__19_1>d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Squirrel.Utility.<>c__DisplayClass13_0`1.<<ForEachAsync>b__1>d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at Squirrel.Utility.<DeleteDirectory>d__19.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at Squirrel.Utility.<LogIfThrows>d__42.MoveNext() 2017-08-29
>   13:04:06> Unhandled exception: System.AggregateException: One or more
>   errors occurred. ---> System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access
>   the file
>   'C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\atom\packages\atom-1.19.4-full.nupkg'
>   because it is being used by another process.    at
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>
>   at System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path, Boolean checkHost)    at
>   System.IO.File.Delete(String path)    at
>   Squirrel.Utility.<>c.<DeleteDirectory>b__19_0(String file)    at
>   Squirrel.Utility.<>c__DisplayClass12_1`1.b__1()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Squirrel.Utility.<>c__DisplayClass13_0`1.<<ForEachAsync>b__1>d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at Squirrel.Utility.<DeleteDirectory>d__19.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Squirrel.Utility.<>c.<<DeleteDirectory>b__19_1>d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Squirrel.Utility.<>c__DisplayClass13_0`1.<b__1>d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at Squirrel.Utility.d__19.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at Squirrel.Utility.d__42.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
>   at Squirrel.Update.Program.d__4.MoveNext()    --- End of
>   inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
>   includeTaskCanceledExceptions)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()    at
>   Squirrel.Update.Program.executeCommandLine(String[] args)    at
>   Squirrel.Update.Program.main(String[] args)
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file
>   'C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\atom\packages\atom-1.19.4-full.nupkg'
>   because it is being used by another process.    at
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>   at System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path, Boolean checkHost)    at
>   System.IO.File.Delete(String path)    at
>   Squirrel.Utility.<>c.b__19_0(String file)    at
>   Squirrel.Utility.<>c__DisplayClass12_1`1.<ForEachAsync>b__1()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Squirrel.Utility.<>c__DisplayClass13_0`1.<b__1>d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at Squirrel.Utility.d__19.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Squirrel.Utility.<>c.<b__19_1>d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Squirrel.Utility.<>c__DisplayClass13_0`1.<b__1>d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at Squirrel.Utility.d__19.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at Squirrel.Utility.d__42.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
>   at Squirrel.Update.Program.d__4.MoveNext()<---

Comment: Based on your logs as it says `directory is not empty`, you can manually delete the directory from `C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\atom` and then retry installing with `Run as Administrator`

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it it,,, i feel dumb .

Comment: still dont know why it vanished ....

Comment: i think probably 2 installers might be running simultaneously if not on foreground then may be in background and believe me I have got much easier error and got stuck :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your logs `Atom installer` is unable to overwrite or write to the folder 
`C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\atom`, so easy way to fix it is to manually delete this folder and then re-run the installed with `Run as Administrator`.
This will fox the issue.